# SSL certificate for a multitenant web app

Tags: azure, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm developing a multitenant web app hosted in azure. Tenants point their domain to my app and this is how I distinguish between them. So client1.com and client2.com both point to myapp.azurewebsites.net but depending on which url a user came from I serve different pages.

How can I add SSL certificate(s) to that website so nobody gets an invalid domain name error?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When you put the website in the correct pricing tier you can add custom domains and ssl certificates yourself.
After you add your domains (client1.com, etc) and after you add your certificats (for client.com,etx) you can set an ssl binding. 
That way it should work.

Here are some useful links: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/ (to add a custom domain to the website)
And here how to add the ssl binding (check step 3) https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site/

[image]